# Spectral decomposition of hilbert modules

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, hilbert-modules

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, $E$ a Hilbert $A$-module and $T:E\rightarrow E$ a bounded self-adjoint regular operator. Is there something like a spectral theorem for Hilbert modules that gives a decomposition of $E$ in relation to the spectrum of $T$? For example, is there an analogue of the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators?

Edit: clarified question with Martin's comments below.

Comment: As stated, the result is false even for $E$ a Hilbert space. You would need $T$ to be selfadjoint, or normal.

Comment: Of course, thanks I've fixed that now.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying: note that as stated the result is still not true in $B(H)$, as there are selfadjoint operators with no eigenvalues. The general form of the Spectral Theorem requires projection valued measures and their integrals. Do you mean something like that, or you want to only consider the analog of the compact operators?

Comment: I see. I'd be interested in both versions, or if you knew of some references? (What I have in mind are Dirac operators acting on sections of a bundle of Hilbert $C^*$-modules over some (possibly non-compact) manifold.)

Comment: I am also very interested in this question. A cursory search gives the paper "A Spectral Theorem for Normal Operators on a Kaplansky–Hilbert Module" by J.D.M. Wright, but he specializes $A$ to be the ring of complex-valued continuous functions on a totally disconnected compact space $S$. Would certainly like the input from operator algebras expert to see whether there are theorems in this generality.